# Inheritance and known type issue

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to use protobuf .net to serialize an instance of a class which is inherited from a base class. When trying to serialize\deserialize i'm getting an exception about "type not expected". As I already read, adding the protoinclude with the derived type to the base wil solve the problem. BUT, my problem is that I can't add the attribute, since I don't know the types that will  derive my base. As I already read, I understand that V2 is going to provide a way to define a type model in order to describe inheritance. So my questions are:

1. When V2 release will be avilable?
2. Is there a workaround in the mean time to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Gil

Answer (score 0):

V2 is available both from nuget and google-code (nuget is a few revs ahead IIRC - and both are a little behind the head). There are a few v1 features not yet re-implemented, but for most purposes you won't notice this. They will be re-added in due course.

Re your problem; that is available via MetaType.AddSubType - however, to use that approach you must be able to reproduce the same int identifiers per-subtype in the future - they are important keys and must not change.

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(SomeType)].AddSubType(7, subType);
```

There is also DynamicType available on "object" properties - however this has a few kinks with inheritance-based models; I would avoid that for now (this too will be rectified shortly).

Comment: Hi mark,
Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand your answer completely.
1. Does the sample you provided in your answer is available at v1 latest release ( "protobuf-net-VS10.msi"?
2. What do you mean by "nuget is a few revs ahead IIRC - and both are a little behind the head"? Sorry for the question, but what is nuget and iirc? I didn't understand from this if there is a final release of V2 to download?
At google code I saw only beta for download ("protobuf-net v2 beta r450.zip"). I tried it but there are  methods which throw not implemented exception.

Thanks
Gil

Comment: @Gil "nuget" is the library download tool inside VS2010 - it allows you to access/update thousands of libraries (such as protobuf-net) easily in the IDE. There is no "final" v2 yet, in as much as there is a whole queue of feature suggestions etc. The "beta" mark persisting is simply due to the outstanding *rarely used* v1 features, such as `.GetProto<T>` (for extracting a .proto scheme from a model) - these will be re-added, but have not been re-written **yet**. So if you need that, v1 may be a better option for now. All every-day features are present.